# Como fazer NumericUpDown retornar ao valor mínimo quando o UpButton é clicado e o valor atual é o máximo?

Tags: c#

Estou usando um `NumericUpDown` em uma aplicação onde o usuário possa definir um horário desejado para que seja realizada uma ação qualquer. São três `NumericUpDown`: um para a hora (de *0* a *23*), outro para minuto (*0* a *59*) e outro para segundo (*0* a *59*).

O problema é que quando o usuário incrementa os valores por meio do próprio botão de incremento do `NumericUpDown` quando o valor atual é o máximo valor configurado (*23* para horas e *59* para minutos e segundos), naturalmente o valor não é incrementado mais. Porém, gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de fazer com que os valores voltem ao mínimo nessa situação (ou seja, para *0*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver seria comparar o valor atual com o valor mínimo e máximo permitido.

Quando o valor atingir o mínimo, altere o valor para o máximo e quando atingir o máximo, altere o valor para o mínimo.

No evento `Click` do `NumericUpDown` faça:

```
private void numericUpDown2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal valor = numericUpDown2.Value;

    if (valor.Equals(numericUpDown2.Minimum)) {
        numericUpDown2.Value = numericUpDown2.Maximum;
    } 

    if (valor.Equals(numericUpDown2.Maximum)) {
        numericUpDown2.Value = numericUpDown2.Minimum;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, @stderr !